# Non-stateless JAXB XML Adapters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a non-static data which I need to use on conversion. How can I transfer this data into my adapter class? Probably can I use a XmlAdapter in JAXB RI without an empty constructor (and without annotation of course)?

```
public class VariableAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Variable> {
  private Map<String, Variable> varMap;
  public VariableAdapter(Map<String, Variable> aVarMap) {
    varMap = aVarMap;
  }
  public Variable unmarshal(String aVarName) {
    return varMap.get(aVarName);
  }
  public String marshal(Variable v) {
    return v.getName();
  }
}
```

Here is my class, which I need to convert from/into XML

```
public class Variable {
  private String name;
  private Object value;
  public Value(String aName, Object aValue) {
    name = aName;
    value = aValue;
  }
  public String getName() {return name;}
  public Object getValue() {return value;}
  public void setValue(Object aValue) {value = aValue;}
}
```

All Variable objects are initialized before XML processing and must be serialized per its name. Variable after unmarshalling can get another value (if its value was changed between serialization/deserialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JAXB will create a new instance of the `XmlAdapter`.  You can call the `setAdapter` method on `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller` to specify a stateful one.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html